# clock_settime C function equivalent in Rust

Tags: rust

Is it possible to set system date and time received via GPS in `Rust`? In `C` I could do it via `clock_settime` builtin function https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/clock_settime.3.html

Comment: Something like [`libc::clock_settime`](https://rust-lang.github.io/hashbrown/libc/fn.clock_settime.html)?